# Force JDialog to get visible before proccessing data?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, swingworker

I have created a `JDialog` in NetBeans and a custom constructor as follows:

```
public AnimatedProgress(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, JTable table) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    progressLabel.setText("Collecting Table Data. . .");
    Object[][] data = getJTableData(table); // Simple method to collect data and store in Object[][] array
    progressLabel.setText("Processing Data. . .");
    processData(data);
    progressLabel.setText("Data Processed. . .");
}
```

Now I called this `JDialog` as:

```
new AnimatedProgress(this, true, dataTable).setVisible(True);
```

My problem is, as Java calls the constructor, all the codes in constructor gets executed first and then the dialog appears with final result.

How can I make my `JDialog` appears first and then process the methods: `getTableData()` and `processData()`??

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling
`Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson -- Yes That is main problem actually. Well I know `swing.Timer` well but there are just two process which are definitely not repeating, and, I do not know how to apply `SwingWorker` here. . .Can you please answer this question with `SwingWorker` code?

Comment: @Asif: Please don't ask for code -- that's up to you to create. Why not look at the tutorial linked to by Andrew Thompson and try to create your own code. Then if you get stuck post your attempt here.

Comment: Ok I will go for it. . .thank you :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson was right. The best solution would be using a `SwingWorker`. See my answer which shows an example of using `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample use of `SwingWorker`:

```
public class BackgroundThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
{
    private JTable table;

    public BackgroundThread(JTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        /*
            If getJTableData() or processData() are not static,
            pass a reference of your class which has these methods
            and call them via that reference
        */
        Object[][] data = getJTableData(table);
        publish("Processing Data. . .");
        processData(data);
        publish("Data Processed. . .");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<String> chunks)
    {
        for(String chunk : chunks) progressLabel.setText(chunk);
    }
}
```

Then change you constructor to this:

```
public AnimatedProgress(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, JTable table)
{
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    setVisible(true);
    new BackgroundThread(table).execute();
}
```

I didn't test it, but I hope it works.

Comment: Oh thanks very much, I just need a structure code as you give out :) I will handle the errors if any occur. . :)

Comment: @Asif if `getJTableData()` or `processData()` contains any change on the GUI, try to transfer it in `process()` method, just to avoid GUI-freezing.

Comment: I got this error while declaring `process()` method: `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

name clash: process(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) in BackgroundThread and process(java.util.List<V>) in javax.swing.SwingWorker have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`

Comment: On editing the line: `class BackgroundThread extends SwingWorker<String, Void>` to `class BackgroundThread extends SwingWorker<String, _String_>` the error eliminated, what happens here?

Comment: I have carried out all the steps successfully, just one last left, after all processing i have to `dispose` the dialog automatically, how can I achieve this? or is there a way that through my `BackgroundThread` i tell the `EDT` that _Yes I have completed my process now u can call `dispose()`_ ?

Comment: Can I use `dispose()` in _override_ `done()` method of `SwingWorker` ? Will it be valid?

Comment: @Asif Yes, you can `dispose()` the dialog in `doen()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The JDialog can't be visible before it is created ==> constructor must be executed fully before visibility change.
I think you should create a myInitialize() method that contains the data fill-ups.
First you make the dialog visible by calling the constructor as now and after that you can call your myIntialize() method to fill up the components with the proper data.

Comment: and where should I call this `myInitialize()` method?

Comment: After the constructor call.
AnimatedProgress progress = new AnimatedProgress(this, true, dataTable);
progress.setVisible(true);
progress.init();

Comment: Actually the whole code in methods `getTableData()` and `processData()` are self executed together with the animation in this `JDailog` (I skip the `Timer` code here though), and I cannot call this code by the event from which I called the `JDialog`...i hope I am clear to you :)